# Метод который принимает на вход строку, и возвращает хэш-мапу(java)

Tags: java-hashmap

Метод который принимает на вход строку (большой текст), и возвращает хэш-мапу, где ключом является строка (слово), а значением число (количество, сколько раз это слово встретилось в тексте).

Понимаю, как создать хэш-мапу

```
Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Понимаю, как заставить java принять строку на вход

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Но без понятия как это совместить в один метод

Answer (score 1):

Разделить текст на слова (split или чего там в джаве)

Для каждого слова проверить, есть ли оно в словаре.
Если нет, то добавить `{слово;0}`, иначе увеличить `value` для данного `key` (слова)

Comment: спасибо, примерно понял как это делается)

Answer (score 0):

```
const g = (text) => {
    let a = text.split(/[ ,.:;!?\n\r]+/);
    let map = {};
    for(let item of a){
        if(map[item] == undefined) {
            map[item] = 1;
        } else {
            map[item] += 1
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Сделал на JS, думаю поймете. Суть - берем строку, травим на нее regexp и split, чтобы обрезать все пробелы, знаки препинания и т.д. затем создаем объект или Map и циклом считаем.